# Нужно вывести N пар простых чисел-близнецов

Tags: c++, математика, простые-числа

Я в общем сам вопрос понимаю, но как его реализовать в С++ не могу понять.

Как я это понимаю: `for(N=n; N+f; N++)` (N-количество чисел которые нужно вывести; f=0, как-то организовать проверку является ли число простым числом, если да сделать проверку на числа-близнецы: Первое число - Второе число!=2, тогда f++; [3-5=2, подходит.. `if(11-7!=2) then f++;`]. И после вывести данные в консоль. ([Что такое числа-близнецы).](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8B)

По некоторым просьбам сказали сделать код, ну вот:

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n, N, f;
    cout << "Введите количество цифр которое нужно найти:" <<endl;
    cin >> n;
    f = 0;
    for (N = n; N + f; N++)
    {
        if ((n - 2) - (n) == 2) then....
        else f++;
        cout << "Парние цифри:" << 1 << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

*Он кстати не рабочий поскольку я так и не понял как то или иное реализировать...*

Comment: А при чем тут количество выводимых **цифр**? А решал бы я так: вывел 3,5, а потом - проверял бы поочередно пары `6n-1`, `6n+1` на простоту. Примерно так... Вряд ли от вас потребуют миллиарды пар :)

Comment: Ну если Вы все знаете, прикрепите пример Вашего кода и опишите проблемы, поможем

Comment: @Harry мне нужно 25 пар (конкретика) чисел-близнецов.
Хмм.

Comment: Чисел - понятно, но вы же пишете "*N-количество цифр которые нужно вывести*"? (P.S. В то, что программист путает цифры и числа, поверить не в состоянии :))

Comment: @Harry я не русский.. всегда щитал что это одно и то же поправил вопрос

Comment: ok, do you understand the difference between digits and numbers? :)

Comment: @Harry да, цифра-знаки, число-количество знаков; я исправил вопросик)                                         

Обычно цифра означает один из следующих графических знаков: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
Источник: Википедия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну я не понимаю, что непонятно в моем комментарии, как решить эту задачу... Вот его перевод в код -

```
bool isPrime(int n)  // Четных чисел у нас все равно не будет, 
{                    // делимость на 2 не проверяем...
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
        if (n%i==0) return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "(3,5)\n";
    for(int n = 1, k = 1; n < 25; ++k)
    {
        if (isPrime(6*k-1)&&isPrime(6*k+1))
        {
            cout << "(" << 6*k-1 << "," << 6*k+1 << ")\n";
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Извинясь за мою глупость, но я убрал "int argc, const char* argv[ ]"  и ничего не изменилось, зачем они тогда?

Comment: На случай передачи параметров в командной строке :) Здесь они не нужны, но поскольку в общем случае всякое может быть - у меня в шаблоне они есть...